# Autohotkey - virtual keyboard / AutoInput

Tags: autohotkey

I have this simply script in Autohotkey:

```
:*:teams::
(
milan
juventus
inter
roma
lazio
napoli
mantova
)
```

When i type *teams* on Notepad my output is the list of teams (milan, juventus..)
if i use a physical keyboard to type *teams* this script work for me
[image: tastiera fisica]

, but if use a virtual keyboard to type *teams* i have no list on Notepad:
[image: virtual keyboard]

and if i run the script to type *teams* automatically

```
WinWait, *new  2 - Notepad++, 
IfWinNotActive, *new  2 - Notepad++, , WinActivate, *new  2 - Notepad++, 
WinWaitActive, *new  2 - Notepad++, 
MouseClick, left,  133,  117
Sleep, 100
Send, squadre
```

the script doesn't replace *teams* with the list of teams
Why the script works only if i type with a physical keyboard?
is there a solution to replace words, sentences with my scripts without using physical keyboard?

Sorry if i am noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Input` command.

```
loop {
    While !RegexMatch(strCapture, "teams$") {
        Input, strUserInput, V L1, {BackSpace}  ; V: visible, L1: Character length 1
        If ErrorLevel = Endkey:BackSpace
            strCapture := SubStr(strCapture, 1, StrLen(strUserInput) - 1) 
        else
            strCapture .= strUserInput
        ; tooltip % ErrorLevel "`n" strUserInput "`n" strCapture "`n" ; enable this to see what actually happens
    }
    SendInput,
    (Ltrim
        {Backspace 5}
        milan
        juventus
        inter
        roma
        lazio
        napoli
        mantova
    )
    strCapture := ""
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Now It's working both virtual keyboard and send commands. It is also possible to run the script integrating copy-paste? I have post a similar question about a similar problem with send command, can u help me please once again? Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644352/autohotkey-sending-from-editor-hotkey-replacing-string

Comment: Just another thing..how can i modify the code to replace 2,3 words with other words? In your code version i can replace only one word. Can u help me please?

Comment: @user149018 To replace strings, you can use `RegexReplace()` or `StringReplace`. I expect you start a new question for it. The question you linked is kind of long and has multiple questions in it. It makes harder for answerers to reply. So I suggest you present problems as less as possible in one post.

Comment: Ok, look here please for replace different words/sentences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660847/autohotkey-replace-different-words-or-sentences