# Autohotkey - Replace different words or sentences

Tags: autohotkey

in this script that I use i can replace only one word *teams*--> *milan, juventus, inter..*
But i want replace many words (not only one word) for example:

[simply word replacement jack-->beta]

```
alfa-->beta
```

[sentence replacement jack-->*jack,john,alfa*]

```
jack

jack
john
alfa
```

This is actually code that i use

```
loop {
    While !RegexMatch(strCapture, "teams$") {
        Input, strUserInput, V L1, {BackSpace}  ; V: visible, L1: Character length 1
        If ErrorLevel = Endkey:BackSpace
            strCapture := SubStr(strCapture, 1, StrLen(strUserInput) - 1) 
        else
            strCapture .= strUserInput
        ; tooltip % ErrorLevel "`n" strUserInput "`n" strCapture "`n" ; enable this to see what actually happens
    }
    SendInput,
    (Ltrim
        {Backspace 5}
        milan
        juventus
        inter
        roma
        lazio
        napoli
        mantova
    )
    strCapture := ""
}
```

How can I modify the code?
It is also possible to run the script integrating copy-paste?

Comment: Considering your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642295/autohotkey-virtual-keyboard-autoinput, you cannot use regular HotString labels for the virtual keyboard. It it correct?

Comment: No, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642295/autohotkey-virtual-keyboard-autoinput i can use your hotstring for the virtual keyboard. I can not understand how can i integrate clipboard (copy-paste) typing, for example, *teams*

Comment: Try to be clear as possible. To which sentence does your "No" refer: "it is correct?" or "you cannot use regular HotString labels"? The code I gave you does NOT use HotString labels but the `Input` command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a For loop to replace the contents, but this would become increasingly tedious to maintain at scale, so YMMV.

The following will use the clipboard contents as the to/from variables, but you can swap it out with a variable as desired (replace "clipboard" with your string variable).

```
F3::
{
    replace := {"alfa":"beta", "gamma":"delta"}
    For start, end in replace {
    StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, %start%, %end%, All
}}
Return
```